# How to make the correct transition to a normal scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Use `swiper` https://swiperjs.com/get-started

My code https://jsfiddle.net/15d8qzwp/

```js
const sw = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  direction: "vertical",
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  speed: 1500,

  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    sensitivity: 1,
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  }
});

sw.on('reachEnd', function() {
  if (sw.isEnd) {
    console.log("end is reached");
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.s1,
.s3 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.s4 {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.swiper {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <section class="s1">Section 1</section>

    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <section class="s2">Section 2</section>

    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">

      <section class="s3">Section 3</section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="s4">Section 4</section>
<section class="s5">Section 5</section>
```

Now scroll to the `last slide` - the part of `section 4` is displayed

[image]

Tell me how to display `section 3` (the `last slide`) at full height, after that the usual scroll for `section 4`, etc.
Thank you in advance